# How to make a picker in react-native keep updated along with AsyncStorage keys?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm currently making an application using react-native with react-native-material-dropdown for my Picker. Simply, my app is about store or something, so you can `add items`, `remove items` (CRUD) and i want my picker is up-to-date with my item in AsyncStorage database.

Everything is fine but i had to re-open my application in order to have new item i just added via "add item" function (or navigation). I'm using expo, react-navigation.

Here is my application : https://ibb.co/qF3vjTt

Here is my "add item" navigation : https://ibb.co/jkdSh04
Whenever I click ok (first ok, don't mind the second one), it will add the item to DB but my picker value is not updating. https://ibb.co/Mhtrqkd
As i mentioned before, I had to re open the app in order to make it updated in picker value.

Here is my "add items" js code (again. it's working for adding item)

```
  tambah = async () => {
    let data = {
      nama: this.state.namaBarang,
      harga: this.state.harga,
      tipe: this.state.tipe
    };
    let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(data.nama.toLowerCase());
    if (value != null) return alert("Barang sudah ada!");
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(data.nama.toLowerCase(), JSON.stringify(data));
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
    alert(`${data.nama} berhasil ditambahkan.`);
  };
```

Here is the JSX code

```
<Button title="OK" onPress={this.tambah} />
```

Here is my main tab code

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { daftarBarang: [] };
  }
  loadBarang() {
    const data = AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then(keys => {
      const stop = keys.length;
      const index = keys.toString().split(",");
      for (let i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
        this.state.daftarBarang[i] = { value: index[i] };
      }
    });
  }
// ......
return (
<Dropdown onPress={this.loadBarang()} label="Pilih Produk..." data={this.state.daftarBarang} />
// ......
);
```

Comment: Your data is daftarBarang. Where are you updating this? This is not being updated anywhere.

Comment: Updated my code, sorry i posted modified code that i used to fix my problem. The updated one is the currently working thing https://ibb.co/ftC8hD5